# JSF app with the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: RichFaces is not defined

Tags: jsf, richfaces

An application is migrated and now there is an issue when een page is opened and in the console I see the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: RichFaces is not defined"
It's a Java application on a Weblogic server.
JSF is old, but the application is new to me, I haven't build the application.

This is a part of the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<f:view
    contentType="text/html"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:win="http://winter.ba.uwv.nl/winter"
>
<html>
    <h:head>
        ...
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <h:outputScript name="/javascript/jquery.timers.js" target="head" />
        <h:outputScript name="/javascript/preloadCssImages.jQuery_v5.js" target="head" />
        <h:outputScript name="/javascript/tooltip.js" target="head" />
        <rich:jQuery />

        <ui:remove><!-- Disable the a4j:loadStyle tags and enable the link tag to use plain setup --> </ui:remove>

        <ui:insert name="head"/>
        <h:outputScript target="head">
        
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery.preloadCssImages();
            ...
        });
           
        </h:outputScript>   
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
    ...
```

The line **<rich:jQuery />** is resulting in:

```
<span id="j_idt7" style="display: none;">
      <script type="text/javascript">RichFaces.ui.jQueryComponent.query();</script>
   </span>
```

And the line **RichFaces.ui.jQueryComponent.query();** is resulting in the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: RichFaces is not defined
> at home.xhtml:13:152
> (anonymous) @ home.xhtml:13

I don't understand why a <span...> tag is added in the head?
It seems to me, but I'm not sure an artifact is missing. I have tried to add the following artifacts to my pom.xml file:

- richfaces
- richfaces-components-ui
- richfaces-ui
- richfaces-components-ui
- richfaces-ui-core-ui

Has someone an idea how to solve "Uncaught ReferenceError: RichFaces is not defined" error?

---- **UPDATE** (after the Answer of Makhiel) ----

1. If we do not add the line rich:JQuery and the page is opnening than an jquery spinner is started, which never ends. It 'hangs' with this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.preloadCssImages is not a function
> at HTMLDocument. (userList.xhtml:17:28)
> at l (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2:16996)
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2:17783)
> at Function.ready (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2:12504)
> at HTMLDocument.A (jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2:9909)

2. This is the output in the browser and at line 13 there is the line which is mentioned by @Makhiel. Right after that line, is the line which gives the error: **RichFaces.ui.jQueryComponent.query();**.

```html
<html>
    <head id="j_idt2">
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />                
        <script>
        /* Fix image caching problem */
            try { document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true); } catch(err) {}
        </script>
        <title>Winter</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/winter/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <!-- This is the line of Makhiel mentioned, so it exists -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces.staticResource/4.5.17.Final/PackedCompressed/packed/packed.js"></script>

        <span id="j_idt9" style="display: none;">
            <script type="text/javascript">RichFaces.ui.jQueryComponent.query();</script>
        </span>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/richfaces.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/richfaces-base-component.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/jquery.component.js">            
        <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                    jQuery.preloadCssImages();
                    //perhaps add delay
                    ...

                });
        </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/richfaces-queue.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/status.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/toolbar.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/richfaces-event.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/togglePanel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/togglePanelItem.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/collapsiblePanel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/collapsiblePanelItem.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/message.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/jquery.position.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/richfaces-utils.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/richfaces-selection.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/AutocompleteBase.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/Autocomplete.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/popupPanel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/popupPanelBorders.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/popupPanelSizer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/component-control.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/popup.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/menuKeyNavigation.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/menu-base.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/menu.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/menugroup.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/menuitem.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/contextmenu.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/tooltip.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/datatable.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/extendedDataTable.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/winter/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces/datascroller.js"></script>
        ...
        </head>
        <body>
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`rich:jQuery` without any attributes doesn't do anything, so you might as well delete it.

You shouldn't need to add anything in your POM, if JSF didn't know what the richfaces tag was it wouldn't be translating it.

Your generated `<head>` should contain RichFaces JS sources, something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/org.richfaces.resources/javax.faces.resource/org.richfaces.staticResource/4.5.17.Final/PackedCompressed/packed/packed.js"></script>
```

This is where the RichFaces object is defined, if it's not on your page (and it sounds like it isn't) you might have a filter in place that blocks it.